# Detect aligned points in set of points OpenCV

Tags: opencv, curve-fitting, hough-transform

Given a set of points on an image, I want to detect groups of aligned points as shown in the figure:
[image: Lines on an image]

How can I do this? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You could detect all the possible line fits and then check the slope for which are (90+/5) degrees..

Comment: I guess answers should employ the `HoughLines*()` functions of the OpenCV library.

Answer (score 7):

This is a good potential application of the [Hough Transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hough_transform). The Hough space for lines is (r, \theta) where r is the distance from origin to closest point on line and \theta is its orientation.

Each point in x-y space becomes a sinusoid in Hough space as shown in the Wiki article.

The places where all the sinusoids intersect corresponds to a single line that passes through all the points.  If the points are not perfectly colinear, the intersection will be "fuzzy".

The simplest algorithm to fit lines to points is to make a rectangular (r, \theta) accumulator array set to zero initially. Then trace a sinusoid for each point into this discrete (r, \theta) space, incrementing each accumulator element by a fixed amount.  Find prospective line fits by looking for large array elements.  The element coordinates give (r, \theta) for the fit.

Tracing the sinusoid is straightforward.  If you have T accumulator bins on the \theta axis then each corresponds to an angle k(\pi)/N for some 0 <= k < T.  So for k in this range, calculate the distance from the origin to the closest point of a line with this orientation passing through the point.  This provides an r value.  If there are R bins on the R axis and Rmax is the maximum value of r, then increment bin (floor(r/rMax*R), k).

Comment: This is the proper way to solve the problem but because I'm not directly processing the image, just the results of finding "blobs" on the image, I would have to completely understand Hough Transforms and write from scratch.  A good thing to do, later....  Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Had another cup of tea and brain cells kicked in!  Created blank image and put location of each object as a line on the new image.  Now I can use a Hough Transform!

Comment: @PhoebeB Yes. And OpenCV has an implementation of the Hough transform already present. We've used with good results (on pre-processed image gradients) for finding boundary lines to be avoided by autonomous robots. Even if you must implement Hough yourself, it's not very hard.

Answer (score 3):

As a start, you can try this:

1. List all lines that can be formed by selecting any two of these points (`n(n-1)/2` ones for `n` points).
2. For any two of these lines, check if they are aligned (i.e. slope diff within say 10 degrees).
3. For each aligned pair lines, you can easily check whether other points are also aligned on these lines. And these points will be the aligned points you need.

Comment: This looks the more doable approach for me.  Thanks.